# Adding values to checkboxes from db table

Tags: drupal-7

I am quite new to drupal 7. I need to add names which come from db table into checkboxes. How do i do that? I have written my callback form function below:

```
function page_second_callback_form($form){
    $result = db_query('SELECT n.names FROM {my_test_tab} n');

    $output ='';

    foreach($result as $item) {
     $output .= $item->names;
    }

   $opt = array($output => $output,);


  $form['check'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'fieldset',
    '#title'    => 'some',
    '#collapsible'  => TRUE,
    '#collapsed'    => TRUE,
  );    
 $form['check']['chk_box'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'checkboxes',
    '#title'    => 'check box title go here.',
    '#required'     => TRUE,
    '#descrfiption' => 'some descriptions for checkboxes.',
    '#options'      => $opt,
);  
$form['check']['submit'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'submit',
    '#value'    => 'Delete',
);  
return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill an array of the database options for the checkboxes, then pass this array to the `#options` property of the checkboxes.

Change your code to be:

```
$output =array(); // the $output should be an array to store the database values.

foreach($result as $item) {
    $output[] = $item->names; // fill the $output array with the database values.
}
```

Then:

```
$form['check']['chk_box'] = array(
    '#type'         => 'checkboxes',
    '#title'        => 'check box title go here.',
    '#required'     => TRUE,
    '#descrfiption' => 'some descriptions for checkboxes.',
    '#options'      => $output, // the changed line.
);
```